# Xlsxwriter Python3 Error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am having troubles with my python3 script, in regards to closing xlsxwriter. I have included workbook.close(), but this seems to result in some kind of error. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
import xlsxwriter
import statistics

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

power = []

for row in list:
    power.append(row)
    worksheet.write(i, col, row)
    col += 1

worksheet.write(i, col, statistics.median(power))

workbook.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 71, in <module>
    workbook.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 311, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 619, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 139, in _create_package
    self._write_shared_strings_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 286, in _write_shared_strings_file
    sst._assemble_xml_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 54, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_sst_strings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 84, in _write_sst_strings
    self._write_si(string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 96, in _write_si
    string = re.sub('(_x[0-9a-fA-F]{4}_)', r'_x005F\1', string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 179, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: @Rahul XlsxWriter is newer but the issue isn't related to the newness or maturity of the module.

Comment: @Rahul There is nothing in the question about reading a file.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't knew you are The Author. I removed my comments and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some variable initialization to the example to get it to compile and it appears to run correctly on Python 2 and 3:

```
import xlsxwriter
import statistics

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

power = []

# I added these variables to the OP program.
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i = 0
col = 0

for row in list:
    power.append(row)
    worksheet.write(i, col, row)
    col += 1

worksheet.write(i, col, statistics.median(power))

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I guess the difference between this and the your example is the contents of the list array.

Could you update your question with an example that demonstrates the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a byte-like object into a string using `.decode`, e.g.  `obj = response.read().decode('utf-8').`

In your case the objects inside list must be of type bytes, convert them into string.

See [Convert bytes to a Python String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)